# fix :Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting a runtime exception `fix:Index` was outside the bounds of the array when running the following code:

```
  char[] delim = { ' ' };
  string sContent = txtcontent.Text;
  string sFind = txtfind.Text;
  string sReplace = txtreplace.Text;
  string sRecontent = txtrepalcecontent.Text;
  //Session["find"] = sFind;
  string[] fileLineString = new string[sContent.Length];
  for (int i =0 ; i < sContent.Length; i++)

   {
      //fileLineString[0] = sContent[0].ToString();
      string[] content = sContent.Split(delim);
      if (sFind == content[i])  ////**error**
          //if (Session["find"].ToString() == content[i])
      {
          string A = sContent.Remove(i, txtfind.Text.Length);
          string S = A.Insert(i, sReplace);
          txtrepalcecontent.Text = S;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
string[] content = sContent.Split(delim);
  if (sFind == content[i])  ////**error**
```

You are iterating over an array of length n m times with m being the length of another array (shorter, because the array is the result of a split, so you are removing character and reducing the length), but still expecting the array to be of length n. This is way you are getting index out of bounds.
To fix it, just move the split before the for-cycle and iterate with the same index:

```
char[] delim = { ' ' };
string sContent = txtcontent.Text;
string sFind = txtfind.Text;
string sReplace = txtreplace.Text;
string sRecontent = txtrepalcecontent.Text;
//Session["find"] = sFind;
string[] content = sContent.Split(delim);
string[] fileLineString = new string[content.Length];
for (int i =0 ; i < content.Length; i++)
{
  //fileLineString[0] = sContent[0].ToString();

  if (sFind == content[i])  ////**error**
      //if (Session["find"].ToString() == content[i])
  {
      string A = sContent.Remove(i, txtfind.Text.Length);
      string S = A.Insert(i, sReplace);
      txtrepalcecontent.Text = S;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string A = sContent.Remove(i, txtfind.Text.Length);
  string S = A.Insert(i, sReplace);
  txtrepalcecontent.Text = S;
```

how to replace without replace function